# Choose N pairs of (job, time slot) with a constraint on the number of different jobs

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am making a solver to choose the best assignment to a set of people for an event, given their availability (chosen in a set $T$ of time slots), jobs preferences (among $J$ possible jobs) and some of other predefined constraints. We refer to a particular pair of *(job, time slot)* as a "shift".

I'm not optimizing the entire workforce at once but instead I assign one person at a time.* Here's an overview of how I modeled the sub-problem:

- Enumerate the set $S$ of all possible shifts ($|S| = |J|\times|T| = 90$ in my case)
- Use an objective function related to the number of people already assigned to each shift (and the need for that shift)
- Find solution $x \in \{0,1\}^{|S|}$ that associates to each element of $S$ a value in $\{0, 1\}$

The constraints are the following:

- Each person can be assigned up to N shifts (depending on their preference)
- Up to 2 shifts during the same day
- No consecutive shifts except when the job remains the same
- **Each person can do only up to two different jobs during the entire event**

I managed to encode all the constraints as a linear program except the last one. Any idea on how that could be done ? If that is not possible at all (which I suspect), what tool can I use to solve this problem ?

---

* I know that is sub-optimal, but finding a better algorithm will probably be the subject of another question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last constraint is also no problem. You already have variables $x_{j,t}$, that say if the person works the $j$th job on the time slot $t$. Now you can introduce new binary variables $y_j$, that represent, if the person works at the job $j$ or not. Then you can model the constraint by:

$$\sum_{j \in J} y_j \le 2$$

The only part left is how you connect the information from the $x_{j,t}$ with $y_j$. But that is also not hard. If any of the $x_{j,t}$ is $1$, then you can force $y_j$ to also be $1$ with the constraints

$$y_j \ge x_{j,t}\qquad\forall t \in T, \forall j \in J$$

and force $y_j$ to $0$ if all $x_{j,t}$ are $0$. This can be done with:

$$y_j \le \sum_{t \in T} x_{j,t}\qquad\forall j \in J$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot ! I'm not used to LP so I would never have found this trick myself. Great to how one's can shift its view of this kind of problems.

Comment: You're welcome. This trick can be used in a variation of different topics. I know it from graph problems (MST, TSP, ...) where you have constraints on the edges, but then also want to apply some additional constraints on the vertices.